# Generating a tabula recta

Tags: beginner, haskell, cryptography

I want an experienced Haskeller to critique my code and offer changes/suggestions (so I can learn the idioms of the language and culture around Haskell).

I've been using a [Tabula Recta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabula_recta) for my passwords and used a Python script someone wrote to generate the table and do table traversal.

I've been wanting to learn Haskell and decided to take on building the same program but in Haskell.

I'm new to Haskell but not functional programming (I have Scheme and Erlang under my belt - Erlang I use in production on a daily basis). I feel like I kept compositional style but I doubt I adhered to idiomatic Haskell.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
{- |
Module      :  tabula.hs
Description :  Generates a tabula recta
Copyright   :  (c) Parnell Springmeyer
License     :  BSD3

Maintainer  :  ixmatus@gmail.com
Stability   :  experimental

Generates and manipulates a tabula recta.
-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad.CryptoRandom
import Crypto.Random

import Data.String.Utils
import Data.List.Split

main :: IO()
main = do
    values <- tabulay ['A'..'Z']
    putStrLn $ "    " ++ join " " (chunksOf 1 ['A'..'Z'])
    putStrLn $ "  + " ++ (take 52 $ cycle "- ")
    putStrLn $ join "\n" (reverse values)

tabulay :: [Char] -> IO [[Char]]
tabulay cmap = tabulay' cmap []
    where tabulay' [] acc    = do return acc
          tabulay' (x:xs) acc = do
            chars <- tabulax 26
            let formatted = [x, '|'] ++ chars
                spaced = join " " (chunksOf 1 formatted)
            tabulay' xs $! (spaced:acc)

tabulax :: Int -> IO [Char]
tabulax cint = tabulax' cint []
    where tabulax' 0 acc    = do return acc
          tabulax' iint acc = do 
            val <- randomChoice characterMap
            tabulax' (iint-1) $! (val:acc)

characterMap :: [Char]
characterMap =
    let 
        cmap = ['a'..'z'] ++ ['A'..'Z'] ++ ['0'..'9']
        symb = [',', '.', '/', '?', '~', '`', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '_', '+', '=', '{', '[', ']', '}', '\\', '|', ':', ';', '"', '\'']
    in cmap ++ symb

randVal :: Int -> IO Int
randVal len = do
    g <- newGenIO :: IO SystemRandom
    let Right (int, _) = crandomR (0, len-1) g :: Either GenError (Int, SystemRandom)

    -- This MUST be strict - otherwise this function will keep too many file handles open
    return $! int

randomChoice :: [Char] -> IO Char
randomChoice ls = do
    randomIndex <- randVal (length ls)
    let val = ls !! randomIndex
    return val
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yet another problem is the usage of lists. `!!` is O(N) operation. Use `Data.Array` instead.

As for randoms, you should call `newGenIO` only once and use the cryptographically secure generator it returned after that instead of creation of new generators each time you need a random character.

Your randVal function should look something like this:

```
randVal :: Int -> SystemRandom -> (Int, SystemRandom)
randVal len g = fromRight $ crandomR (0, len-1) g
```

It accepts old generator state and returns the new state to use in subsequent generations. To simplify passing the generator state around you can use a state monad. But there is already such monad - the `CRand` monad and corresponding `CRandT` monad transformer to combine random number generation with other monadic computations.

The example from the documentation for `CRand` fails to typecheck because of monomorphism restriction - `getRandPair` looks like a value but it isn't, so the compiler detects a potential problem. You can disable it for now by adding `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` before `module Main where` line.

Also, it is not clear how the `SystemRandom` generator works. It is secure, but I think it's not adviced to drain system entropy source. I'd rather use it just to seed `HashDRBG` from `Crypto.Random.DRBG`, which is SHA512-based RNG.

Here is a hint:

```
type Gen a = CRand HashDRBG GenError a

randValM :: Int -> Gen Int
randValM len = getCRandomR (0, len-1)

randomChoice :: [a] -> Gen a
randomChoice ls = do
    randomIndex <- randValM (length ls)
    return $ ls !! randomIndex
```

Your `tabulax` function will remain the same, but will operate in a different monad, so it's type will change to `randomChoice :: [a] -> Gen a`. Note also that I used `getCRandomR` from `Control.Monad.Crypto.Random` to make use of the monadic helper to implicitly pass the cryptogenerator around and perform error checking.

Your main will change too:

```
printGenerated values = do
    putStrLn $ "    " ++ join " " (chunksOf 1 ['A'..'Z'])
    putStrLn $ "  + " ++ (take 52 $ cycle "- ")
    putStrLn $ join "\n" (reverse values)

fromRight (Right a) = a

generate = evalCRand $ do
    a <- tabulay ['A'..'Z']
    return a

main = do
    g <- newGenIO :: IO HashDRBG
    printGenerated $ fromRight $ generate g
```

The idea is that we extracted `generate` - a pure function which accepts a generator and returns generated data. `evalCRand` is used to extract the inner `a` value from monadic `Gen a` value. It accepts two arguments: a monadic computation in `Gen` monad and initial state of random generator. There is also `runCRand` function which returns the final state of the generator in addition to the value, but we don't need the final state here.

I abused the do-notation here to help you understand code better. I would write `generate` and `main` shorter:

```
generate = evalCRand $ tabulay ['A'..'Z']

main = newGenIO >>= printGenerated . fromRight . generate
```

Your `tabulatex'` function is already there in the standard library. It is `Control.Monad.replicateM`:

```
import Control.Monad hiding (join)

tabulax :: Int -> Gen [Char]
tabulax cint = replicateM cint $ randomChoice characterMap
```

`tabulatey'` is also there in `Control.Monad`, it's `mapM`:

```
tabulay :: [Char] -> Gen [[Char]]
tabulay = mapM $ \x -> do 
            chars <- tabulax 26
            let formatted = [x, '|'] ++ chars
                spaced = join " " (chunksOf 1 formatted)
            return spaced
```

Next step is to use immutable arrays:

```
import Data.Array.IArray

tabulax :: Int -> Gen [Char]
tabulax cint = replicateM cint $ randomChoiceA arrMap

arrMap :: Array Int Char
arrMap = listArray (0, (length characterMap) - 1) characterMap

randomChoiceA ls = do
    randomIndex <- randValM $ 1 + snd (bounds ls)
    return $ ls ! randomIndex
```

Now `randValM` seems to be perverted: we convert bounds from tuple to size and back. Eliminating the extra conversion we get rid of `randValM` completely, as getCRandomR and `bounds` perfectly fit each other:

```
randomChoiceA ls = do
    randomIndex <- getCRandomR $ bounds ls
    return $ ls ! randomIndex
```

Now we can shorten it by desugaring do-notation and using function composition and infix operator sections:

```
randomChoiceA ls = getCRandomR (bounds ls) >>= return . (ls !)
```

And even more using `<$>` from `Control.Applicative` (which is the same as `fmap`):

```
randomChoiceA ls = (ls !) <$> getCRandomR (bounds ls)
```

Finally, we can extract `separate = join " " . chunksOf 1` as it is used 2 times and shorten `tabulay` just for fun:

```
tabulay :: [Char] -> Gen [[Char]]
tabulay = mapM $ \x -> separate <$> ([x, '|'] ++) <$> tabulax 26
```

and get rid of ugly `-1` in array bounds:

```
arrMap :: Array Int Char
arrMap = listArray (1, length characterMap) characterMap
```

So the final source is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
module Main where

import Control.Monad.CryptoRandom
import Crypto.Random.DRBG
import Data.String.Utils
import Data.List.Split
import Control.Monad hiding (join)
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Array.IArray

printGenerated values = do
    putStrLn $ "    " ++ separate ['A'..'Z']
    putStrLn $ "  + " ++ take 52 (cycle "- ")
    putStrLn $ join "\n" (reverse values)

fromRight (Right a) = a

generate = evalCRand $ tabulay ['A'..'Z']

main = newGenIO >>= printGenerated . fromRight . generate

separate = join " " . chunksOf 1

tabulay :: [Char] -> Gen [[Char]]
tabulay = mapM $ \x -> separate <$> ([x, '|'] ++) <$> tabulax 26

tabulax :: Int -> Gen [Char]
tabulax cint = replicateM cint $ randomChoiceA arrMap

arrMap :: Array Int Char
arrMap = listArray (1, length characterMap) characterMap

randomChoiceA ls = (ls !) <$> getCRandomR (bounds ls)

characterMap :: [Char]
characterMap =
    let 
        cmap = ['a'..'z'] ++ ['A'..'Z'] ++ ['0'..'9']
        symb = ",./?~`!@#$%^&*()-_+={[]}\\|:;\"'"
    in cmap ++ symb

type Gen a = CRand HashDRBG GenError a
```

Comment: Reading this some more - thank you for putting so much time into it, very helpful. A lot for me to learn obviously as your use of >>= is new to me. I'll have to learn more about monads I guess (yes, I'm that new to the language).

This will be a good reference for me, thank you again.

Comment: I rewrote this and it is MUCH faster than what I had wrote - I assume that's because with your code the newGenIO generator is being called only *once* rather than 676 times!! See I thought the generator had to be called multiple times in order to get a new random value each time - which when I originally wrote the program had "too man files open" errors - so this makes more sense now.

Comment: Also I attempted to use replicateM before but I had issues with the IO Char type being expected - same thing with mapM (hence why I custom wrote the accumulators).

Comment: Question, is there a benefit to using function composition other than succinctness? When is it considered appropriate to use and not? This: join "\n" (reverse values) could just as easily be written as: (join "\n" . reverse) values EDIT I've answered my own question with this URL: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/12229728/805266 . There is a separate discipline of functional-level programming, which is different from pointfree programming in Haskell. And regarding composition - one subtle advantage is that `(.)` is associative (that is, `(f . g) . h == f . (g . h)`) while `$` is not. For the same reason `>=>` is a 'better' way to compose monadic computations than `>>=`. This makes refactoring easier, as you can always extract a part of long composition chain into a separate function.

Answer (score 3):

Too much IO — most of this code could be pure. Seed the pure random generator with crypto source, you don't need to read from it every time, if you really want crypto source for this. `tabulay'` and `tabulax'` look suspiciously like `map`. `symb` in `characterMap` could be written with string notation.

Comment: That was my suspicion (re: IO) but I noticed every time I tried to pass the integer from randVal I would get type errors with regards to "expected type Int, got IO Int instead"...

Most of the information on the internet I read said I could pass IO Int to functions expecting Int as long as I was inside of a do block.

Could you provide some examples of how I might do it the way you are talking about?

Comment: @lxmatus: The type error is because you can't escape from IO (well, without using unsafe functions). What I'm proposing is removing the need of keeping the RNG in IO: RNG by nature is pure, the only thing you're using IO for is reading from urandom or whatnot. Take a look at System.Random instead of using Crypto.Random. You can initialise the generator from `main`, using external seed (like urandom or just time, really) and then pass it along to pure functions. I'll write you an example in a bit.

Comment: The only problem with System.Random is that it isn't Cryptographically secure random number generation... That's what I want to achieve with the tabula program.

Comment: @lxmatus: What do you need SPRNG for? Oh, passwords. Anyway, you can seed from secure source and then use pure generator and it'll have pretty much the same effect.

Comment: Hmmm, everything I've played around with so far has produced nothing but type errors :-/ if you have any free time I would love (even just small) an example to help me a long.